# Unable to resolve module Error in React Native Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am getting some weird error on adding Redux Provider in my App.tsx. I have all modules installed and did the "delete node_modules folder and npm install " process already, still can't figure out the issue

```
Unable to resolve module ../../../../src/redux from
MY_PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\@reduxjs\toolkit\dist\redux-toolkit.cjs.production.min.js:
```

App.tsx

```
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import BottomTabs from "./src/containers/BottomTabs";
import { store } from "./src/redux/store";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <BottomTabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
}
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import themeReducer from "./themeSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    theme: themeReducer,
  },
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

themeSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { DEFAULT_DARK_THEME } from "../theme/DefaultDarkTheme";
import {
  DEFAULT_LIGHT_THEME,
  DEFAULT_LIGHT_THEME_ID,
} from "../theme/DefaultLightTheme";
const messageSlice = createSlice({
  name: "theme",
  initialState: DEFAULT_LIGHT_THEME,
  reducers: {
    toggleTheme(state) {
      if (state.id === DEFAULT_LIGHT_THEME_ID) return DEFAULT_DARK_THEME;
      return DEFAULT_LIGHT_THEME;
    },
  },
});

export const { toggleTheme } = messageSlice.actions;
export default messageSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

check your "dependencies" in package.json you'll figure it out there is no "@reduxjs/toolkit". just terminate all the process and add "reduxjs/toolkit" first.

by doing "yarn add @reduxjs/toolkit" or you can also go with npm

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem too.

Perhaps, you made `redux` directory in your application root and made an alias name `redux` for using absolute path in your `babel.config.js`?
It conflicts the name of pure `redux` import.

In my case, I realized the name conflict, and removed the setting.
But it still happened, then I could resolve it with running `expo start -c` for clearing cache.

I'm using Expo though, `react-native start --reset-cache` may solve the problem if you are not using Expo.